# List of NoSQL DB available for electron app which are easy to sync with couchbase?

Tags: electron, couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway, nosql

I have a Desktop application, which is built using Electron.
Lets say, this application, runs offline most of the time. and I  want to sync the data with the cloud database ( couchbase).
I would like to know, which NoSQL database will be suitable for this application.

Comment: Couchbase is a NoSQL DB so I am not sure I understand your question.

Comment: There are two DB, one is couchbase ( hosted in main server), other is "XXX" DB which is hosted in client side. Now, i want to choose "XXX" DB such that, it'l' be easy to sync with couchbase ( hosted in main server).

Comment: On client side you can use the Sync Gateway's REST API. Or Pouch DB, or Couchbase lite.

Comment: I'm using angular and couchbase lite doesnt have support for angular. PouchDB is one option.  can we use sync gateway REST API as client DB?

Comment: Yes you can absolutely do that.

Comment: Also to mention RxDB https://github.com/pubkey/rxdb